# Validator for input field inside composite component is never fired

Tags: jsf, facelets, validation, composite-component

I've created some Facelets to make developing our pages easier.  Particularly, I've created a series of Facelets for input components.  I have 1 Facelet, `<xxx:input />` that displays a label around the input field.  Beyond that, I have Facelets like `<xxx:inputText />` and `<xxx:inputSecret />` that render the actual input field.  Each of these makes use of `<xxx:input />` to display the label.  The  Facelet looks something like this:

```
<html ...>
   <composite:interface>
      ...
   </composite:interface>
   <composite:implementation>
       <label><h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.labelText}" /></label>

       <composite:insertChildren />
   </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

The `<xxx:inputText />` Facelet would then look like this...

```
<html ...>
   <composite:interface>
      ...
   </composite:interface>
   <composite:implementation>
      <xxx:input labelText=...>
         <h:inputText id="myinput" ... />
      </xxx:input>
   </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Everything renders just fine, but I am having troubles when trying to add `<f:validator />` or other validation tags.  From what I've read, I have to add a  tag to my  Facelet.  So, I added `<composite:editableValueHolder name="myinput" targets="myinput" />` line in the interface section.  However, I still do not see my validator being fired.  I have something like this in my .xhtml file...

```
 ...
    <xxx:inputText value="...">
      <f:validateLength minimum="10" for="myinput" />
    </xxx:inputText>
    ...
```

Regardless of the input I enter, the validator never seems to fire and I never get an error message.  A coworker suggested that it is due to the target ID I am using and the fact that it is wrapped by the `<xxx:input />` Facelet.

Do I need to incorporate the parent component ID in my target definition?  Is there something else that I'm missing?  It works just fine if I exclude the `<xxx:input />` Facelet, so I'm assuming it's something related to that, but don't know how to solve it.  Any help you can provide is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu0111/index.html#wrap it seems to have exactly what your looking for...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the `for` attribute of the validator to match the `name` of the `<composite:editableValueHolder>`.

```
<xxx:inputText value="...">
  <f:validateLength for="myinput" minimum="10" />
</xxx:inputText>
```

You also need to make sure that the `<composite:editableValueHolder>` is specified in **both** composites, thus also the `input.xhtml` one. Here's a complete example which works just fine for me on Mojarra 2.1.12:

`/resources/components/input.xhtml`:

```
<ui:component
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="label" required="true" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="input" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
       <h:outputLabel for="input" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
       <cc:insertChildren />
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

`/resources/components/inputText.xhtml`:

```
<ui:component
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="label" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="input:text" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <my:input id="input" label="#{cc.attrs.label}">
            <h:inputText id="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
        </my:input>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Usage in some `test.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 12188638</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <my:inputText label="foo" value="#{bean.input}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="10" for="input" />
            </my:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:messages/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

#### See also:

- [How to specify a validator for an input component inside a composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780703/how-to-specify-a-validator-for-an-input-component-inside-a-composite-component/8789982#8789982)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you aware of the [`<h:outputLabel>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLabel.html)?

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.labelText}" />
```

And the fact that you can just inline EL in template text without explicit need for `<h:outputText>`?

```
<label>#{cc.attrs.labelText}</label>
```

Have you noticed that your label is also missing the `for` attribute which should reference the ID of the input element which the label should be referring to?

```
<h:outputLabel for="someId" ... />
<h:inputText id="someId" ... />
```

Comment: I actually had the 'for' attribute in my validator.  Merely a transcription error.  I have corrected my question to reflect it.  Additionally, I have made use of <h:outputLabel />.  I just didn't have the reference code with me at the time to copy-paste it in.  For what it's worth, adding 'for' doesn't help me in this exact situation.  If I remove the outer facelet (<xxx:input />) and only have the facelet for the input field itself, it works just fine.  That's why I am assuming it's the facelet-in-a-facelet thing causing the problem.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to specify `<composite:editableValueHolder>` in the `input.xhtml` composite as well.