# How to evaluate a FacesComponent property inside a custom component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

Lately, I've been working on a dynamic form project but is stop with a custom component problem. What I have:

A faces component for formField:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "formField")
public class FormFieldCompositeComponent { 
    private boolean email;
}
```

A custom component jsf:

```
<o:validator for="email_text" validatorId="emailValidator" disabled="#{not cc.email}" />
```

OR

```
<c:if test="#{not cc.email}">
    <f:validator for="email_text" validatorId="emailValidator"></f:validator>
</c:if>
```

OR

```
<f:validator disabled="#{not cc.email}" for="email_text" validatorId="emailValidator"></f:validator>
```

And the validator:

```
@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator { }
```

My problems are:

1.) If I use an ordinary f:validator, like the one I use above and then use c:if to enable/disable it, then it will not work. According to some articles I've read it's because f:validator validates on build time, not on render time.

2.) If I use o:validator, it works but the problem is every time you hit submit a new line of invalid email error is added to p:messages. Example I clicked submit button 3 times, then I get 3 times the email error.

Any idea?

More info (anatomy of the project)
Example I have a page user with field email, it will include the following custom components:

```
+user.xhtml
 +formPanel
 +formField (this is where the validator is defined)
  +formButtons (the action button)
  +p:messages is defined
```

user.xhtml

```
<formPanel>
  <formField field="email" />
  <formButtons />
</formPanel>
```

Command button is like (formButtons):

```
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" rendered="#{cc.attrs.edit}"
    value="#{messages['action.save']}"
    action="#{cc.attrs.backingBean.saveOrUpdate()}" icon="ui-icon-check"
    ajax="#{cc.attrs.ajaxSubmit}">
    <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.backingBean.lcid != null}">
        <f:param name="cid" value="#{cc.attrs.backingBean.lcid}" />
    </c:if>
</p:commandButton>
```

The p:messages as defined on formPanel:

```
<p:messages id="formMessages" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" redisplay="false"></p:messages>
```

Note:

1.) What I've noticed is that the validator is called n times, where n is the number of submit or click done.

xhtml - https://github.com/czetsuya/crud-faces/blob/master/crud-faces/src/main/webapp/administration/user/user.xhtml

the tags - https://github.com/czetsuya/crud-faces/tree/master/crud-faces/src/main/webapp/resources/tags

bean component - https://github.com/czetsuya/crud-faces/tree/master/crud-faces/src/main/java/org/manaty/view/composite

Comment: Maybe use `redisplay=false` on `p:messages`.

Comment: Hi, the p:messages' redisplay is already set to false so this is not the issue.

Comment: As asked in your previous question on this subject, please post an SSCCE. The usage of `for` attribute is so strange in this context that I am not able to recreate your code and therefore not be able to reproduce your problem. At least, the `for` attribute should only be used **outside** the composite implementation, on the template client. See for a real world example also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780703/how-to-specify-a-validator-for-an-input-component-inside-a-composite-component/

Comment: Hi Balus, sorry for that. I'm updating the post above for real world examples.

Comment: Oh OK, you're thus nesting composites. It's only quite some code not in SSCCE flavor, but I can now start somewhere. I'll look closer if I've more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no chance for the f:validator so I push through o:validator and come up with a workaround. Need to catch if the error is already in the FacesMessages list:

```
boolean match = false;
for (FacesMessage fm : context.getMessageList()) {
    if (fm.getDetail().equals(message)
            || fm.getSummary().equals(message)) {
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!match) {
    throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
}
```