# How to add a Validator to ui:include?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, uiinclude

Mojarra 2.1

I have the facelet (namespaces ommited) `inc.xhtml`:

```
<f:view>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" required="true">
        <f:validateLength maximum="32" />
    </h:inputText>
</f:veiw>
```

I need to inlucde the view into another facelet adding an additional validator for the `name` input. I tried this:

```
<h:form id="createForm">

   <f:validator validatorId="customUniqueNameValidator" for="name"/>

   <ui:include src="/inc.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="bean" value="#{myBean}" />
   </ui:include>
   <!-- other markup -->
</h:form>
```

And it didn't work. I got the exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /mailing/create.xhtml @13,85 <f:validator> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@7595a5c
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyNested(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:87)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at ua.com.winforce.online.admin.http.filter.ReInitJSFSessionManagedBeanFilter.doFilter(ReInitJSFSessionManagedBeanFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Tiny What's wrong with the post?

Comment: @Tiny That has probably something to do with random down-voting. Good posts're sometimes downvoted without any reasons....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` attribute of the validator (and converter) tag works only when nested in a composite component. See also [How to specify a validator for an input component inside a composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780703/how-to-specify-a-validator-for-an-input-component-inside-a-composite-component)

In case you don't want to use a composite component, your best bet is to pass the individual validator attribute as an `<ui:param>` and use `<c:if>` to conditionally set the desired validator with the attribute.

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/input.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{myBean}" />
    <ui:param name="maxlength" value="#{3}" />
</ui:include>
```

```
<ui:composition xmlns="..." ...>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}">
        <c:if test="#{not empty maxlength}">
            <f:validateLength maximum="#{maxlength}" />
        </c:if>
    </h:inputText>
</ui:composition>
```

That said, consider registering the `input.xhtml` as a tagfile to make it less verbose.

```
<my:input bean="#{myBean}" maxlength="#{3}" />
```

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: don't use a `<f:view>` around the include/tagfile. Use at most `<f:subview>` to ensure ID uniqueness. See also [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con). And, you'd better place the XHTML file in `/WEB-INF` folder. This is already demonstrated in code snippets posted so far. See also [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)

Comment: As far as I know using jstl-tags within facelets is never good. So, the better solution would be writing a composite component with for example `validateUnique ="boolean"` attribute, right?

Comment: "Never good" is a myth caused by JSF 1.x + JSP heritage and ignorance of starters about the JSF/JSTL lifecycle. Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense I assure that the above is one of the right ways of using JSTL in JSF 2.x + Facelets. It is a great tool in conditionally building the view (where ignorant starters would more than often fall back to "dynamically" creating components in Java side while that only makes things yet worse and verbose).