# Why is reference to composite component validator not resolved?

Tags: validation, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I want to attach custom validator to one of my input fields inside composite component, however the validator is not firing at all. 
I have done it exactly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780703/how-to-specify-a-validator-for-an-input-component-inside-a-composite-component/8789982#8789982), but I can't get it working. Also in my code, the reference to composite component input validator (`for="validateService"`) is marked red `cannot resolve symbol 'validateService'`. What am I doing wrong?

component.xhtml

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="service"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="validateService" targets="#{cc.attrs.service}"/>
</cc:interface>
```

page.xhtml

```
<cc:myComponent id="input"
        service="#{myBean.service}"
    <f:validator validatorId="serviceValidator" for="validateService"/>
</cc:myComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding validator directly inside the composite pomponent input field like this

```
<p:inputText id="service"
             validator="serviceValidator"/>
```

But i still have no idea why above solution doesn't work.